# fresco attribute viewAspectRatio with databinding

Tags: android, fresco

When I use like this `fresco:viewAspectRatio="@{carItemModel.radio}`, the Android Studio would always show this error:

> ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'fresco:viewAspectRatio' with parameter type java.lang.float on
>   com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView.

Don't this attribute support databinding?